# Flutter: I don't get translated product from in-app purchases

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, google-play-console

Probably a more related question to Google Play Console in general but because I'm using Flutter I'll consider it could be related.

I have 2 products properly setup on my console and I'm getting both of them on my app. So no problems related to the package itself either (https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase).

Despite I have 2 languages I don't get the translated one when I change the language on my app. And this is normal, because I change it locally so Google Play Console has no idea (I guess).

---

Here is my product translated:

[image]

After changing the app language I still getting always English:

[image]

Comment: As solution I thought about having just one language in GPC and include there the code that I use in my app for the translations so I'd have something like "offer.portfolios" instead "2 portfolios"

Comment: On iOS there's a [localized title](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/4411247270069e8b4d4969652b6c2d1d9b694d82/packages/in_app_purchase/lib/src/store_kit_wrappers/sk_product_wrapper.dart#L211), on Android I looked for "localized" or "translated" properties and found nothing.
I suggest [opening an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new/choose).

Comment: so you confirm that this is a Flutter issue then?

Comment: If you're not getting the title localized when accessing [title property](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/in_app_purchase/lib/src/billing_client_wrappers/sku_details_wrapper.dart#L81) in `SKUDetailsWrapper` then yes I do think it's a Flutter issue. Because as I said its counterpart on iOS there's a [localized title](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/4411247270069e8b4d4969652b6c2d1d9b694d82/packages/in_app_purchase/lib/src/store_kit_wrappers/sk_product_wrapper.dart#L211) in `SKProductWrapper`

Comment: done: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51550

Comment: my temporary solution doesn't work. Too long description